# Доменная аутентификация ldap3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, active-directory, kerberos

Позвольте поднять вопрос использования ldap3 в среде windows.

Можно ли установить связь  (conn.bind() – необходимо для администрирования: создания/модификации объектов) по доменной аутентификации – без пароля? 
По обрывочным комментариям на форумах у меня сложилось мнение, что это можно реализовать через Kerberos, что в рамках ldap3: KERBEROS = GSSAPI = 'GSSAPI'

И в документации есть описание:
https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/bind.html

Но, кажется, работает только на линуксе - вылетает ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gssapi'
```

И даже есть какое-то решение:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710365/how-to-install-gssapi-python-module-on-windows

Но завести это дело как-то не удается.
Кто-нибудь занимался администрированием домена, проходя аутентификацию через KERBEROS?

Пример используемого подключения с NTLM:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

server = Server('servername.local',  get_info=ALL) 

conn = Connection(server, user='DOMAIN\\User', password='****', authentication=NTLM)
print(conn)

conn.start_tls()
print(conn)

conn.bind()
print(conn.result)

print(conn.bound)
```

Более полная инструкция, предложенная @MaxU:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279503/passwordless-python-ldap3-authentication-from-windows-client/52280673#52280673

Однако проблема в подключении остается (права админа на домене имеются):

```
C:\Users\UserProfile\PycharmProjects\untitled10\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/UserProfile/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UserProfile/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.bind()
  File "C:\Users\UserProfile\PycharmProjects\untitled10\venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 530, in bind
    self.open(read_server_info=False)
  File "C:\Users\UserProfile\PycharmProjects\untitled10\venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 56, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "C:\Users\UserProfile\PycharmProjects\untitled10\venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 147, in open
    raise LDAPSocketOpenError('unable to open socket', exception_history)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: ('unable to open socket', [(LDAPSocketOpenError('socket ssl wrapping error: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host',), ('10.127.37.7', 636))])
```

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280673/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU ,спасибо - эта инструкция более полная, чем я находил. но проблема всё еще остается - unable to open socket

Comment: ('10.127.37.7', 636): @Alex, вы пытаетесь установить SSL соединение, замените IP адрес на FQDN, как Вам все мануалы советуют. В том линке, который привел `MaxU` даже рекомендуют проверить через SPN имя сервера - смотрите комментарий Jason Dec 5 '18 at 19:35